# Data return null from view to controller in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, view, null

I have a function in my controller for check user email that is active or not?

```
  public async Task<IActionResult>ActiveEmailAccount(EmailActiveAccountViewModel active)
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _userService.ActiveAccount(active);
        switch (result)
        {
            case ActiveEmailResult.Error:
                ModelState.AddModelError("email", "error");
                break;

            case ActiveEmailResult.NotActive:
                ModelState.AddModelError("email", ""NotActive");
                break;

            case ActiveEmailResult.Success:
                ModelState.AddModelError("email", "active
                break;
            }

        ViewData["active"] = result;
        return View(active);
    }
```

and this is  my repository to get it:

```
  public async Task<User> GetUserByActiveCode(string activeCode)
    {
        return await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.EmailActiveCode == activeCode);
    }

    public async Task<bool> CheckEmailActiveCode(string activeCode)
    {
         return await _context.Users.AnyAsync(u => u.EmailActiveCode == activeCode);
         
    }
```

and in service I get it from service:

```
      public async Task<User> GetUserByActiveCode(string activeCode)
    {
        return await _userRepository.GetUserByActiveCode(activeCode);
    }

    public async Task<ActiveEmailResult> ActiveAccount(EmailActiveAccountViewModel active)
    {
        var activeEmailExist=await _userRepository.CheckEmailActiveCode(active.EmailActiveCode);

        var user = await _userRepository.GetUserByActiveCode(active.EmailActiveCode);

        if (activeEmailExist== null )
            return ActiveEmailResult.Error;

         if (activeEmailExist)
        {
            user.UserState = UserState.Active;
            _userRepository.UpdateUser(user);
            await _userRepository.SaveChange();
            return   ActiveEmailResult.Success;
        }
       
        return ActiveEmailResult.NotActive;
    }
```

I receive active code in controller as a view model:

```
 public class EmailActiveAccountViewModel
{ 
    public string EmailActiveCode { get; set; }

}

public enum ActiveEmailResult
{
    NotActive,
    Success,
    Error,
}
```

and when I want to check it and trace it with break point , it will return just null
for example this code from database:

https://localhost:44385/account/ActiveEmailAccount/ddd8915deba74659be3ca89fdc118f14

why it returns just null and doesnot accept :ddd8915deba74659be3ca89fdc118f14

in view I write just view data for check it and has @model of EmailActiveAccountViewModel

```
<div class="alert alert-success"> @ViewData["Active"] </div>
```

/////Edited////

How can I show these result in separated P Tag in view? should I check with if ?

Comment: First debug in controller before go to view.In ViewData["active"] = result; what is the result value u got?

Comment: @DOTNETMVCDev yes I debug it in controller result is success, but  it shows: EmailActiveCode=null It should give :ddd8915deba74659be3ca89fdc118f14 right

Comment: @DOTNETMVCDev I don't understand why EmailActiveCode became null in each trace? it doesn't accept it from view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send the request:`https://localhost:44385/account/ActiveEmailAccount/ddd8915deba74659be3ca89fdc118f14` to the `ActiveEmailAccount` action, **in this case you can not receive the value** of `EmailActiveAccountViewModel` model.

You need send the request like: `https://localhost:44385/account/ActiveEmailAccount?EmailActiveCode =ddd8915deba74659be3ca89fdc118f14`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I change it and again doesnt work , but I set a  rout and it works :). Thanks so much.

Comment: now but I see just the success message , how can I change "success" to a sentence on view? i want show more that one word success. I mean how can I check if in view with view data

Comment: Hi @masoudmazloum, you need modify your ActiveAccount function to return string or json with sentence.